# get contents from an entry box in gtk-rs with a button

Tags: rust, gtk-rs

I was trying to make a button that would get the contents of an entry box and print it to the terminal but I couldn't really find anything that helped. Could anyone help me?

I looked for solutions but didn't really find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I'll put some example code.

```
let button = Button::builder() // button with the name of button
    .label("button")
    // other traits for the button would go here but I just wanted it to be simple

let user_input = gtk::Entry::buidler(); // text box with the name user_input
    .placeholder_text()

button.connect_clicked(move |_| {
    let final_input = user_input.text(); // when the button is clicked final_input will take on the text that is in the text box at the time of the button click.
    println!("{}", final_input);
```

}